# Is there a single word for "copied & pasted"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word alternative to "copy & pasted" in:

> I copy & pasted that into the document.

Comment: Mostly just *copied* will do, since it pretty much implies that you made the copy in order to use it somewhere else.

Comment: Well, there's [copypasta](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=copypasta).

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Comment: @RobertCartaino - I understand, an won't ask any more. On the other hand, remove the tag, or keep it but when selected alert the user they are not permitted to post these types of questions. Changing rules without alerting users first is not the best thing in the world to encouraging people to ask questions. Also, 5 ups, *no* downs and a favorite in a relatively short time... some people thought it was interesting an no one though it was a bad question.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/can-i-say-copied-and-pasted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Copied" is perfectly apt alone.

Answer (score 8):

I would prefer "pasted" over "copied": I pasted it into the document.

Pasting implies that the object of the paste was previously copied, while it is entirely possible to copy something and never do anything else with it.

But surely if you used either "copied" or "pasted" by itself, the meaning would be clear.

Comment: You're not incorrect, but using copied in the sentence structure given also implies the object was pasted: "copied into that document".  And my preference for "copied" is because it has meant "duplicated in another place" for hundreds of years. Monks "copied" texts into beautifully illuminated books. "Pasted" is much more of a neologism.

Comment: +1 Both copied and pasted alone are fine and imply the other, but I'd also choose pasted as it seems more direct. Also when monks copy stuff, it's not an exact digital copy like when I Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V some text. (Neologisms can be well suited for new activities.)

Comment: @JonathanVM I rather suspect that copying and pasting is a newer concept than cutting and pasting, which existed long before computers.  I still remember finding a class agent's speech in the trash at a college reunion.  It was typewritten, and entire paragraphs had been moved around with the help of a pair of scissors and a roll of tape.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need a single word, *[copy-paste](http://www.wordnik.com/words/copy-paste)* has enough antecedents online and in mainstream publications to support its use.

> By launching with a circulation equal to or greater than the market
>   leader, its new paper would immediately start getting advertisements
>   which allowed it to break even within four years in most markets. This
>   allowed it to *copy-paste* this strategy with uncanny precision in
>   multiple markets -- Rajasthan in 1996, Gujarat in 2003 and Punjab in
>   2006.
>
> [--Forbes, "Bucking the Times of India"](http://www.forbes.com/2010/10/14/forbes-india-mission-impossible-dna-and-the-times-of-india_3.html)

Comment: *Copy-pasted* is fine, but a single *copied* or *pasted* seems more elegant to me.

Comment: @Hugo True, but neither captures the entire process; they both imply actions that someone _not_ of the copy-paste generation might miss. "I _copied_ it into the document." "Isn't that plagiarism, young fella?" "I _pasted_ the quote." "Sounds sloppy to me, young man."

Comment: Would the past tense of "copy-paste" be "copy-pasted" or "copied-pasted"?

Comment: @phoog It appears _copy-pasted_ is [more prevalent](http://www.wordnik.com/words/copy-pasted), and it makes sense if you're capturing the entire process as a single compound word. (Besides -- _copied-pasted_ is awfully pedantic, don't you think?)

Comment: Actually "copied-pasted" sounds more natural to me, but I attribute that not to pedantry but rather to my inability to think of "copy-paste" as a single word.  Perhaps that will change eventually (and perhaps around the time that it begins to be spelled "copypaste").